# SPARQL query against DBPedia to get all property-value of the item

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, information-retrieval

I am a novice in Semantic Web and I would like to retrieve all property-value pairs of "apple" from DBPedia using SPARQL query. Below I have written the query in http://dbpedia.org/sparql editor, but it returns no any results.Could you tell me where I make a mistake, please?

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
prefix dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
prefix prov: <http://www.w3.org/ns/prov#>
prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
prefix dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix dct: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

select * where {<http://http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple> ?property ?value}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `http://` twice. Also, the correct URI for the query is `/resource/`, not `/page/`.

Working query:

```
select * where {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple> ?property ?value}
```

Keep in mind this will give you information about the fruit, not the company.

Comment: Thank you so much @svick , I understood my mistake. One more thing I would like to ask: when executing that query it misses some results starting with "is " keyword in property section of  http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple such as "is dbo:product of"  "is dbo:species of " and so on. Could you tell  how to handle with this issue ? Thanks in advance

Comment: @coder That's the reverse relation: `select * where {?value ?property <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple>}`.

Answer (score 2):

I am giving you the query which will give you information about Apple Company rather than apple Fruit.

```
PREFIX dbprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
PREFIX db: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
SELECT ?property, ?value WHERE {db:Apple_Inc ?property ?value}
```