# SPARQL: Get all properties we see in some DBpedia entity

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I basically try to recover with sparql all the properties of the company entity "Apple_Inc."
looking at `http://dbpedia.org/page/Apple_Inc`. I see for example the properties "is dbo:developer of", and "is dbo:cpu of".

But with this code

```
select distinct ?property where {
  ?instance a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Company> . 
  ?instance rdfs:label ?name.
  filter(regex(?name, "Apple Inc")).
  ?instance ?property ?obj .
}
```

I recover only a part of properties, and none of the two examples.

Comment: "is dbo:developer of" are incoming properties, i.e. where Apple Inc. is the object. Thus, use a UNION with two triple patterns, one with outgoing and one for the incoming properties. Don't forget, if you look at RDF dataset as a graph, it is directed.

Comment: ahr ya ! thx. just saw that the same question is answered there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002389/sparql-query-against-dbpedia-to-get-all-property-value-of-the-item

Comment: Also consider `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Apple_Inc>`.

Answer (score 2):

Hey simple solution of your problem. When in the DBpedia frontend `is <something> of` is shown it indicates that the entity that is described on the page you are looking for is the object of for the property not the subject.

For example the triple `(dbr:IOS_8,dbo:developer,dbr:Apple_Inc.)` will be shown in the frontend as `is developer of` because apple is the object not the subject oft the triple.

The following query should do the job:

```
  select distinct ?prop where {
  {?apple a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Company> . 
  ?apple rdfs:label ?name.
  filter(regex(?name, "Apple Inc"))}.

  {{?x ?prop ?apple} union {?apple ?prop ?y}}}
```