# How to find all the properties of a country with its name in sparql?

Tags: sparql

I have some problems of the following query:

Find everything about the country whose name is Afghanistan
in language English (“everything” means all properties of the country).

I'm new to SparQL and try several methods but none of them work, can someone explain steps to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SPARQL query against DBPedia to get all property-value of the item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38002389/sparql-query-against-dbpedia-to-get-all-property-value-of-the-item)

Comment: *"I'm new to SparQL and try several methods but none of them work"* - show what you tried